# How to translate .js files in Django and Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm using Wagtail and Django and I'm trying to translate the content in `html` templates and `js` files.

The content in `html` templates is added correctly to `.po` files but the strings from js files aren't added at all.

The structure of my project is as follows:

[image]

The `urls.py` file inside `webDealers` folder is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^api/', include('API.urls')),

    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'), name='set_language'),
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),

    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

The `settings.py` is as follows:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'    
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'    
USE_I18N = True    
USE_L10N = True    
USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = [('en', 'English'), ('fr', 'French'), ('nl', 'Dutch')]

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

All `.js` files are in static folder inside webDealers folder.

I've added `<script src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>` to the `<head>` tag and I've added `gettext("String to translate")` in .js file where the string needs to be translated.

But when I run `django-admin makemessages -l en` inside `locale` folder I get only translations from html files and not from js files.

And I'm using **Django==2.1.2**

Any advice how to translate strings in js files?

**UPDATE**

When I run

`django-admin makemessages -d django -l nl`

it gets all strings from html files and put them inside locale folder in **root** folder (`root/locale`).

But when I do

`django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l nl`

it gets all .js strings and put them inside locale folder in `root/webDealers/locale`.

I want to have all translations in one place

Answer (score 1):

When calling `makemessages`, you need to pass `--domain js` or `--extension js` to pick up translatable strings in .js files. See the Django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files

Comment: The problem is when I run `django-admin makemessages -d django -l nl` it gets all strings from html files and put them inside locale folder in root folder, but when I do `django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l nl` it gets all .js strings and put them inside locale folder in `root/webDealers`. I want to have all translations in one place